# Supplying a ID to many partial views from a parent view without exposing sensitive ID's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We are using a friendly Name URL route scheme. Basically using a combination of the Principal Identity and a friendly name this can be mapped back to an identity internally (Person ID). So a route like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(string.Empty, "{friendlyname}/Products/{action}", new {controller = "Products", action = "List"});
```

Would map to a URL like this:

```
    Adam/Products/List
```

This all works fine and abstracts away the internal Id of the named person which is required as well.

The problem is our Views are comprised of many partial views. When there are rendered by using the @Html.Action method they ultimately need the PersonID but from the URL we only have the 'friendly name'.

I have thought about this for a while and there are two solutions to my mind:

1. Pass the 'friendly name' into each of the controller action methods that return the partial views and internally the method will have to do a lookup on the currently logged in identity and the friendly name. This will give the PersonID to me and I can then efficiently query from then on. The only problem with this apporach is that due to the multiple partial views I will be querying on the currently logged in identity and friendly name for each partial view call which is innefficeint and I feel I should only have to write this code once.
2. Somehow query in the view and get the PersonID so it can be passed to each @Html.Action call so the partial view controller methods will not have to do that lookup themselves saving round trips to the database for the same shared informtion. The problem with this is that I am not sure of a way of doing this cleanley in the view using the DI that we use through the rest of the application.

Any thoughts on approach to would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the Id to the session variables and access it from within the views with:

```
@{var personId = int.Parse(Session["PersonId"])}
```

Then you can pass it directly to partial views from the Parent without it hitting the client or having to pass parameters to any controllers.

**Update**

You could also access the session variable from the Controller if you wanted to do the work there instead without roundtripping to the database.

**EDIT**

If you put the property in a model and pass it to a page that post's back then the model will not persist between posts.

If for example your controller does:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(ViewModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       // Logic Here
   }
   return View(model)
}
```

when the page is reloaded, the model will have forgotten about the ID.

There are a couple of ways around this. Either use @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
which will put the property in the rendered HTML, which if it is truely a sensitive piece of information, is bad.

Or you can rebuild the view model on each subsequent postback.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Marc. Thank you for your response. I have just figured it out using the model. I will post the answer now.

Comment: Ok apparently I can't answer for another 8 hours. I will update when I am allowed to.

Comment: I'll update my answer with what I assume you are going to do but with a few pitfalls noted.

Comment: That is pretty much it. Thank you for noting the pitfalls. I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc states I could you the Session to deal with this but I have gone with using the Model as he has stated in his update. If the parent View Controller action takes in the friendly name it can do the lookup, put the PersonID into the model and then any Partial Renders can have the models value passed into them in the parent View Controllers Action's view. An example is shown below (this is demo code but it hopefully gets the point across, I would **never** use a static data context in real code)

Home controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string friendlyName)
    {
        int pupilId = Data.People.Single(x => x.Name == friendlyName).PersonId;
        HomeIndexViewModel homeIndexViewModel = new HomeIndexViewModel {PupilId = pupilId};

        return View(homeIndexViewModel);
    }
}
```

Home Index View

```
@model SharingInformationBetweenPartials.Web.Models.HomeIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>    
@Html.Action("DisplayPersonDetail", "Person", new {Model.PersonId})
```

The PersonController's DisplayPersonDetail method can then present the respective data it wishes using the passed in PersonId:

```
public class PupilController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DisplayPupilDetail(int pupilId)
    {
        Person person = Data.People.Single(x => x.PersonId == pupilId);
        return View(person);
    }
}
```

I did try what I thought was this before but I must have got something wrong as the ViewModels properties were getting shown in the URL which is what I was trying to get away from. Anyway, I hope this helps anyone else who may be looking to do something similar. If you have any questions then let me know.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[Bind]` attribute to specify the exact properties a model binder should include in binding or use `Exclude` parameter on the attribute to exclude **PersonId**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPerson([Bind(Exclude = "PersonId")] Person person)
{
    //do domething
}
```

You can also use `[ReadOnly]` attribute that model binder will understand and not assign to that property.

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public int PersonId{ get; set; }
```

But the best approach is to use separate ViewModels: one only for viewing and one for editing.

```
public abstract class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }

}

public class PersonCreateVM : Person
{
   //no PersonId here
}

public class PersonEditVM : Person
{
   public int PersonId{ get; set; }
}
```

This approach is maybe a "overkill" but when used properly and with AutoMapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/ it's an ease to work with.